# Bloch's theorem on $x$-$y$ coupled potential

Tags: homework-and-exercises, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, optical-lattices

Say I have the following lattice potential:
$$V(x,y)= V_0\left(\cos ax+\cos by+\cos(ax+by)\right)$$
This is a periodic function of $x$ and $y$, so Bloch's theorem is applicable...

I want to use it to compute the 2D band structure of the lattice, but the derivation seems complicated when you have the $\cos(ax+by)$ term, is there a standard way to deal with this issue?
Or am I obligated to compute the band structure along some specific directions as is done in most condensed matter textbooks ($\Gamma-M-\Gamma$ and things like that)?

Comment: Using a formula for a cosine of sum could help :)

Comment: What exactly are you struggling with here? Yes, the potential does seem inseparable even after expanding the cosine of the sum, but this shouldn't stop you from formulating the reduced eigenfunction problem in the unit cell and then solving it numerically as a finite 2D problem with periodic boundary conditions, having $\vec k$ as a parameter. Just substitute the Bloch solution and cancel out the $\exp(i\vec k\vec r)$ terms, and you have your equation.